# Scroll a panel using drag and drop gwt

Tags: gwt, drag-and-drop, scroll

I am trying to scroll a panel by mouse. I looked over drag and drop and I can`t figure out if it is possible using drag events to scroll a panel or is it better using mouse move event, mouse over and mouse out etc.

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Although modern GWT [supports](http://webcentersuite.blogspot.com.es/2012/04/native-gwt-drag-and-drop.html) DnD, its implementation is not so good, so it is better that you select one 3party library for that. You have [gwt-dnd](https://code.google.com/p/gwt-dnd/) or [gwtquery-dnd-plugin](https://code.google.com/p/gwtquery-plugins/wiki/DragAndDropPluginForGWTDeveloppers). IMO the second one is easier to use and much more powerful.

But I dont think DnD can help you to move the scroll, since it is designed to move all the draggable element and drop over another one.

Maybe what you need is something similar to the [scrollwidget](http://mobilegwt.appspot.com/showcase/#ScrollWidgetPlace%3a) in [mgwt](http://www.m-gwt.com/), it is designed for mobile devices, but it has an implementation for desktop, so hopefully you could either use the library or copy the approach to your implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case you will use gwtquery, keep in mind that it's out of date. So, you will need to put the newest jquery and jquery-ui libraries into the corresponding jar and edit the gwt.xml files accordingly. It's not a big deal, but otherwise you would put your code under the risk of misfunction in newer browsers. By the way, it depends on the usage you would make of jquery-like functionality.